# Converting the watch command into a unit file systemd

Tags: linux, bash, systemd

I've got a shell script as follows

ss.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
opFile="custom.data"
sourceFile="TestOutput"
./fc app test > $sourceFile
grep -oP '[0-9.]+(?=%)|[0-9.]+(?=[A-Z]+ of)' "$sourceFile" | tr '\n' ',' > $opFile
sed -i 's/,$//' $opFile
```

The requirement is that I need to use this script with the watch command. And I'd like to make this into a systemctl service. I did it as so.

sc.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
watch -n 60 /root/ss.sh
```

And in my /etc/systemd/system,

log_info.service

```
[Unit]

Description="Test Desc"
After=network.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/root/sc.sh
Type=simple

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

When I run systemctl start log_info.service, It runs but not continuously the way I'd like it to.

On running sytemctl status log_info.service,

```
info_log.service - "Test Desc"
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/info_log.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2016-09-12 08:17:02 UTC; 2min 18s ago
  Process: 35555 ExecStart=/root/sc.sh (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 35555 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Sep 12 08:17:02 mo-b428aa6b4 systemd[1]: Started "Test Desc".
Sep 12 08:17:02 mo-b428aa6b4 sc.sh[35654]: Error opening terminal: unknown.
Sep 12 08:17:02 mo-b428aa6b4 systemd[1]: info_log.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Sep 12 08:17:02 mo-b428aa6b4 systemd[1]: info_log.service: Unit entered failed state.
Sep 12 08:17:02 mo-b428aa6b4 systemd[1]: info_log.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Any ideas as to why it's not running right? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: the key is `Error opening terminal: unknown.`  `watch` needs to write to a terminal, but services do not have access to one.   Why do you want this to be a service?

Comment: Ah. How interesting. Well, because running this script as a foreground one, causes that terminal session to become occupied. What else would you suggest? Background?

Comment: If you don't want it to occupy the terminal, I'd recommend either not using `watch` or running something like `screen` or `tmux` so you can have one window running that and others that you are doing other work in.  Bonus to this: you can reconnect to the same terminals if you login remotely and the things you're doing will survive an ssh disconnect

Comment: This is all being done remotely. Running of both scripts is all on a remote system. Which I don't really have permission to install third party applications on. And for ease of running, we wanted to make it a systemctl call. Any other ideas, sir?

Comment: Are you sure `screen` and `tmux` are unavailable?  They may be there already.  Failing that, I'd probably either open 2 windows if I wanted to have that up all the time or just episodically run it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the error message shows, `watch` can be only used from a terminal:

```
Error opening terminal: unknown
```

But your requirement quite probably *isn't* to use the script with `watch`. Your requirement is to *run it every 60 seconds,* and `watch` is the tool you ended up choosing.

The most common method to run a script every 60 seconds would be *cron* – e.g. a `* * * * *` cronjob would be run every minute. With systemd .services you can use a .timer unit for the same purpose:

```
# foo.timer
[Unit]
Description=Do whatever

[Timer]
OnActiveSec=60
OnUnitActiveSec=60

[Install]
WantedBy=timers.target
```

Then instead of starting the .service, you start the .timer instead, and it periodically tries to start the .service on its own.

Comment: Ah, I hadn't looked carefully enough at the script to see its only point was to modify a file, not display output (which I lept to).  This is for sure the way forward then instead of faking it with the terminal like I had been discussing in comments.

Comment: Thank you both for your help. Regarding this solution, could you please run me through the procedure again, I'm new to systemd services. This foo.timer file you've created, it's to run every 60 seconds. But is it still a unit file for systemd? Where does this file call my ss.sh script that I need to run every 60 seconds?

Comment: It's a unit file for systemd. It doesn't call your script. It repeatedly starts the corresponding `.service`, _which_ then calls your script.

Comment: So my initial log_info.service file must still exist then? And I still don't understand where this foo.timer is calling my other log_info service file, if that's the case

Comment: If the names differ, you specify the service unit's name in `[Timer] Unit=`. Otherwise `foo.timer` will try to look for `foo.service` by default.

Comment: Thanks grawity. Last question, in my log_info.service, I call my ss.sh right?